# Building designs into WordPress and Plugins

Tags: wordpress

I want to build a new design into WP (not make a theme for anyone to use) but I was wondering is there anything specific you have to do to make sure plugins still work?

What about plugins you use on the current theme? Will they automatically work on the new design or do you have to do something for them to continue working?

**Edit:** To elaborate further, I have a site that currently uses a WP theme, however I want to get a new design created for it and then build that design into WP. I'm just wondering what I need to do to make sure plugins (new and existing) work on the new theme as I will be coding it.

Comment: Not getting the requirement, can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the procedure would be like this :-

1. Create your design, then make the html for the same.
2. In the existing theme put your html tags properly and add your css in the style.css
3. Just keep in mind that you don't remove any wordpress functions without knowing it.
4. And for plugins, dont remove the below functions :-

   - In header.php there is a function `wp_head();`, this helps the plugins script to embedd scripts.
   - In footer.php there is a function `wp_footer();` this also helps the plugins to embedd scripts.

Hope these steps help you, let me know if there is any other confusion.